# What these strange TXT records in my default OVH DNS config mean

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, txt-record

Can somebody tell me please, what this TXT records means?

```
www                       IN TXT    "l|pt"
www                       IN TXT    "3|welcome"
```

these 2 TXT records appears when i reset my DNS zone configuration, in every my domain.

Comment: Sounds to me like it may have some OVH-specific purpose. Check their documentation or with their support?

Answer (score 6):

Based on [this post at OVH community forums](https://community.ovh.com/t/a-quoi-servent-ces-entrees-txt-par-defaut/3627) in French, it seems to be automatically added when domain is created in order to display the default webpage.

Rough translation of the French message:

> These records are used to display the web page "Félicitation votre domaine vient d'être créé chez OVH" ["Congratulations your domain name has just been registered with OVH"] (txt - welcome) in French (TXT - fr)

In your case it will be in Portuguese `pt` as the original question on the French forums was for:

```
www IN TXT "3|welcome"
www IN TXT "l|fr"
```